# Random toggle switching off if all selected

Tags: javascript, html

Among the 3 toggle button if all of them is selected then automatically one toggle should switch off. I shouldn't not be able to select all the three.

I tried to go with setInterval which check the conditions every second but it didn't work.
When setInterval get control,it eventually switch offs all the buttons

```js
let zval, aval, asval;

const zaid  = document.getElementById('zaid')
const anas  = document.getElementById('anas')
const asgar = document.getElementById('asgar')

zval  = zaid.checked;
aval  = anas.checked;
asval = asgar.checked;

zaid.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (zval == false) {
    zval = true
    zaid.checked = true;
  } else {
    zval = false
    zaid.checked = false;
  }
})

anas.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (aval == false) {
    aval = true
    anas.checked = true;
  } else {
    aval = false
    anas.checked = false;
  }
})

asgar.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (asval == false) {
    asval = true
    asgar.checked = true;
  } else {
    asval = false
    asgar.checked = false;
  }
})

let arr = [zaid, anas, asgar];

setInterval(check, 1000);

function check() {
  let arr2 = [zval, aval, asval]

if (zval == true && aval == true && asval == true) {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    arr2[val] = false;
    arr[val].checked = false;
    console.log(arr2)
  } else {
    console.log('else')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="" id="zaid">
    <label for="zaid">Zaid</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="" id="anas">
    <label for="anas">Anas</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="radio" name="" id="asgar">
    <label for="asgar">Asgar</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because `arr2[val] = false` only modifies `arr2` and not `zval`/`aval`/`asval`.

Comment: Use checkbox instead of radio button

Comment: This feels bad UX, user doesn't have real control over their selections. If it's not purpose to tease the user, I'd build a set of checkboxes, and limited the amout of possible checks, [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/mnz1wcf8/). Notice the id'less markup and high reusability of the code in the fiddle snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you would only like a max of 2 items to be clicked at a time... So I would implement it like this.

Basically you have an array to track the order of how the buttons were clicked and the 1st one will automatically be unchecked once 3 are checked.

See code below (HTML left unchanged):

```
const containerElement = document.querySelector(".container");

const checkedArr = [];

containerElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

const inputSelected = e.target.closest("input").id;

if (checkedArr.includes(inputSelected)) {
return;
}

checkedArr.push(inputSelected);

if (checkedArr.length === 3) {
 const itemToUncheck = checkedArr[0];
 const inputElement = 
 document.querySelector(`input[id="${itemToUncheck}"]`);
 inputElement.checked = false;
 checkedArr.shift();
 }
});
```

Comment: Working good. But I didn't understood what you have done. Can you please explain me it's working wherever you like 'in here' or 'in discord' (username- mohdzaid07)

Answer (score 0):

1- radio buttons are not checkboxs, use `<input type="checkBox"`
2- prefer to use `change` event instead of `click`
3- there is no needs to use `setInterval()` method, just un-check last checkbox if ther is more than two.

You can simply do this ?

```js
const
  chkBx3   = [...document.querySelectorAll('#zaid, #anas, #asgar')]
, chkCount =_=> chkBx3.reduce((nb,chk)=> nb + (chk.checked?1:0), 0)
  ;
chkBx3.forEach( cbx => 
  {
  cbx.addEventListener('change', () =>
    {
    if (chkCount() > 2) cbx.checked = false;
    });
  });
```

```css
label {
  display : block;
  cursor  : pointer;
  }
```

```html
<label> <input type="checkBox" id="zaid">  Zaid  </label>
<label> <input type="checkBox" id="anas">  Anas  </label>
<label> <input type="checkBox" id="asgar"> Asgar </label>
```

Comment: Yeh checkboxes would be better option given they are universally known to allow multiple selections.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it's not what I meant. Can we have contact via discord (username-mohdzaid07)